# Arabic letter data save to database as "?"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, datatable, oledb

I'm uploading data to DB table using excel sheet

I'm uploading data to `ProductStatisticsTemp` table

In that table I have following columns

- Product_ID
- ProductNameEn
- ProductNameAr

this the upload data POST method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["file"].FileName);

            if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ExcelFiles/") + Request.Files["file"].FileName;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                }

                Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

                //connection String for xls file format.
                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                //connection String for xlsx file format.
                else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                excelConnection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                if (dt == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                int t = 0;
                //excel data saves in temp file here.
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    t++;
                }

                OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);

                using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                }
            }

            if (fileExtension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".xml"))
            {
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ExcelFiles") + Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName;

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                }

                Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation);
                // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
                xmlreader.Close();
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                string query = "Insert into ProductStatisticsTemp(Product_ID,ProductNameEn,ProductNameAr) Values('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2] )";
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("FileUpload", "FileUpload");
    }
```

But in here data saving smoothly , but `ProductNameAr` fields Arabic letters values save as "?"

ex: If excel value `حساب التوفير للاستثمار Albrka` 
then its saving in database table as `???? ??????? ????????? Albrka`

How to save as exact format in the excel sheet

ps. this `ProductNameAr` data type in Database table is NVARCHAR

Comment: You should try to bisect the problem. Does the problem happens during the READING from the Excel or during the WRITING to the DB?

Comment: But I can already see the problem: don't compose INSERT in that way (composing a string with the values). Use `SqlParameter`!

Comment: @xanatos can I have some example please

Comment: Try looking around for "insert sqlparameter c#"... You should be able to find many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You use non-Unicode string literals `'value'` when you should use Unicode literals in the form `N'value'`
- You better rewrite as parameterized SqlCommand passing the values using [AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`string query = "Insert into ProductStatisticsTemp(Product_ID,ProductNameEn,ProductNameAr) Values(@Product_ID,@ProductNameEn,@ProductNameAr)";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_ID", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
     ...etc...`

- You don't need to re-create and open the `SqlConnection` inside the loop

Comment: I'm getting following error `'SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlCommand' could be found`

Comment: sorry, that should be cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(). see MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx